# Learning Curves fitting

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot learning curves for my logit model, but I get the error below, even though I adjusted the `array = np.linspace(0, dataframe.shape[0])` with the shape of the inputed parameter. Could there be some sort of data loss ? As I see an excess of 225k rows between the expected value and the input data, but I have no idea where.

```
def get_learning_curves(dataframe, model, X, y):
#check for overfitting
    
    array = np.linspace(0, dataframe.shape[0])
    train_sizes = array.astype(int)
    # Get train scores (R2), train sizes, and validation scores using `learning_curve`
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator=model, X=X, y=y, train_sizes=train_sizes, cv=5)

    # Take the mean of cross-validated train scores and validation scores
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, label = 'Training score')
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, label = 'Test score')
    plt.ylabel('r2 score', fontsize = 14)
    plt.xlabel('Training set size', fontsize = 14)
    plt.title('Learning curves', fontsize = 18, y = 1.03)
    plt.legend()
   
    return plt.show()
```

```
get_learning_curves(pre, LogisticRegression(), X_pre, y_pre)
```

```
pre.shape
>>>(125578, 23)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: train_sizes has been interpreted as absolute numbers of training samples and 
must be within (0, 100462], but is within [0, 125578].
```

Comment: Is your data set heavily imbalanced when it comes to the classes? And what happens if you set `train_sizes = [20_000, 50_000]`? And how does your input look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get is self-explanatory and means:

> the absolute number of training samples must be at least 1 and cannot exceed 100462

That is because of the cross validation used by `learning_curve`. Apparently, cross validation will reserve 1 of `k` folds for testing the model. With `n` being the absolute number of samples, this means `n/k` samples will be reserved to test the model. Contrariwise, this means you can at most specify `n - n/k` as a subset sample size to train the models. This is why the boundary in your case is `125578 - 125578/5 = 100462`.

To fix your problem you have to specify the correct interval to choose the sample sizes from in your code. If you want to use absolute numbers for the sizes, one way to achieve this could be to change:

```
array = np.linspace(0, dataframe.shape[0])
```

to

```
array = np.linspace(1, int(dataframe.shape[0]*0.8))
```

This solution will respect the boundaries for a 5-fold cross validated approach.

Comment: @ArthurLanglois did this answer your question? If yes, please accept it and consider upvoting. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)